# How do I solve the leap year function in Python for Hackerrank?

Tags: python

I cannot for the life of me solve this challenge on Hackerrank. The closest I got it was to 4/6 passes.
Rules:
In the Gregorian calendar three criteria must be taken into account to identify leap years:

```
The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
    The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
        The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
```

Code:

```py
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    # Write your logic here
    if year%400==0 :
        leap = True
    elif year%4 == 0 and year%100 != 0:
        leap = True
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: the logic is much simpler if you reverse the criteria

Comment: If you see as per Gregorian Calendar(as the explanation of the code states), the years 2000 and 2400 are leap years, while 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 and 2500 are NOT leap years.

Answer (score 10):

You forgot the `==0` or `!=0` which will help understand the conditions better. You don't have to use them, but then it can cause confusion maintaining the code.

```py
def is_leap(year):
  leap = False

  if (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0): 
      # Note that in your code the condition will be true if it is not..
      leap = True
  elif (year % 100 == 0) and (year % 400 != 0):
      leap = False
  elif (year % 400 == 0):
      # For some reason here you had False twice
      leap = True
  else:
      leap = False

  return leap
```

a shorter version would be:

```
def is_leap(year):
   return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

Comment: And integer will be seen as "trueish" if not equal to zero. An explicit comparison is not required.

Comment: yes, but leap = true if `not year%4`, etc. so better to add the `==0` or `!=0` to avoid the confusion

Comment: In any case your extremely short explanation does not really say the what the issue is. You should improve it.

Comment: please let me know what is not clear.. would be happy to add

Comment: The answer was your comment on the third conditional.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
def is_leap():
    leap = False
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
        leap = True
    return leap
```

Answer (score 1):

This code might be easy for some of the people to wrap their head around

def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

```
# Write your logic here
if year%4==0:
    leap=True
    if year%100==0:
        leap=False
        if year%400==0:
         leap=True

return leap
```

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))

Answer (score 1):

If we split the question point by point.

- Actual question:
  The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
  The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
  The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
- Explaining it : If a year is divided by 4, then its a leap year.
- If this is divided by 100 but not 400 after being divisible by 4,
  then its not a leap year.
- If this is divisible by 4, 100 ,400 , then its a leap year.

Basically, nested if

```
    if(year % 4 == 0):
        if(year % 100 == 0):
            if(year % 400 == 0):
                leap =True
            else:
                leap=False
        else:
            leap=True
    else:
        leap=False        

    return leap
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap=False
    check =lambda year : year :year%4==0 and (year%400==0 or year%100!=0)
    leap=check(year)
    return leap

year =int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value."

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if year%4 == 0:
      if(year%100 != 0 or year%400 == 0):
         leap = True
    return leap
```

Answer (score 0):

#simplest solution for beginner

```
n = int(input('Enter year to check if it is leap year.'))
if n % 4 == 0 and n%100 != 0:
    leap = 'True'
elif n % 100 == 0 and n%400==0:
    leap = 'True'
else:
    leap = 'False'

print('the entered year is,'+leap)
```

Answer (score 0):

def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

```
# Write your logic here
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    leap =  True
elif year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0:
    leap =  False
elif year % 400 == 0:
    leap = True
elif year % 4 != 0:
    leap = False
return leap
```

year = int(raw_input())
print is_leap(year)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if(year%4==0):
        #century year check
        if(year%100==0):
            #century leap year check
            if(year%400==0):
                leap=True
        else:
            leap=True
    return leap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0:
    return True
elif year%4==0 and year%100!=0 and year%400!=0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Most answers will benefit from an explanation to help visitors hone in on the important elements of your solution. Explanations increase long term value allowing uture visitors to learn from & apply your knowledge to their own code, keeps quality of SO high, & encourages the use of SO platform as a knowledge base, rather than a "give me the code" or, free coding service. Eplanations are usually quicker to digest/understand than strictly interpreting code, & helps distinguish your solution with other solutions. Well crafted answers are more often upvoted

Answer (score 0):

```
n = [int(input("Enter a year in four digit: "))]

a = list(map(lambda x: "is a Leap year" if x%4 == 0 or ( x % 100 != 0 or x % 400 == 0) else "is not a Leap year" , n))

print(f"{n[0]} {a[0]}")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62990800/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

def is_leap(year):
leap = False

```
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    leap = True
elif year % 400 == 0 and year % 100 == 0:
    leap = True

return leap
```

Answer (score 0):

I just try with this:

```
    def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    # Write your logic here
    if (year%4 ==0 and year%100 !=0) or year%400 ==0:
        leap = True
    else:
        leap = False

    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

if year can be evenly divided by 4 and 400 is `True` but if it can be evenly divided by 100 is `False`

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution for the problem. We want the number to be divisible with 4 no matter what. So year % 4 will need to be true for the output to be bool True as well. Then we have to consider if the number which is divisible with 4 can be divided to 400. If the number is divisible to 100 but not 400 it should give us bool False. That is why we should check divisibility to 400 and non-divisibility to 100  together and use or statement.

```
def is_leap(year):
leap = False

if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
    return not leap
else: 
    return leap   

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    # Write your logic here
    if (year%4 ==0):
        if (year%100 == 0) and (year%400 ==0):
            leap = True
        elif(year%100 == 0) and (year%400 !=0):
            leap = False
        else:
            leap = True 
    else:
        leap = False
    return leap

year = int(input())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

**HackerRank Problem  - An extra day is added to the calendar almost every four years as February 29, and the day is called a leap day. It corrects the calendar for the fact that our planet takes approximately 365.25 days to orbit the sun. A leap year contains a leap day.
In the Gregorian calendar, three conditions are used to identify leap years:
The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap years.
Solution is the below Python Code.**

```
def is_leap(year):
leap = False

# Write your logic here
if (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0): 
  # Note that in your code the condition will be true if it is not..
  leap = True
elif (year % 100 == 0) and (year % 400 != 0):
  leap = False
elif (year % 400 == 0):
  # For some reason here you had False twice
  leap = True
else:
  leap = False
return leap
```

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))

Answer (score 0):

Try this @Charles Thompson, this passed all test cases for me.

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if year%4 == 0:
        if year%100 == 0:
            if year%400 == 0:
                leap = True
            else:
                leap = False
        else:
            leap = True
    
    
    return leap
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False 
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    elif year %4 == 0 and year % 100! = 0 and year % 400!= 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
  
year = int(raw_input())
print is_leap(year)
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Same answer as this one posted earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556497/2227743

Answer (score -1):

def is_leap(year):
leap = False

```
# Write your logic here
if year%4==0:
    leap= True
    if year%100 ==0 and year%400==0:
        leap = True
    if (year%100 == 0) and (year%400 != 0):
        leap = False

return leap
```

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))

Comment: Was 2000 yes or no a leap year? Hint: it was an exception to the exceptions ... so ...?

Answer (score -2):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    d4 = year%4
    d100 = year%100
    d400 = year%400
    
    if  d4  == 0 :
        if d100 != 0 or d400 == 0 :
            leap = True
    else :
        leap = False
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```